# Display value on Google Bar chart vertically

Tags: google-visualization

I am using a ColumnChart of google charts
and using DataView i am displaying values for the bar and line
Bar and line chart on same graph i am displaying using

```
series: {
0: { targetAxisIndex: 0 , type: "bars"},
1: { targetAxisIndex: 1,  type: "line"},
},
```

Also i am getting the data from service : using json
The annotations are overlapping in my case due to high numbers. Searching for a solution.
Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @nikki, what are you asking for actually ...?

Comment: an example would really help...